# Tengo este error Warning: mysqli num rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli result, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy implementado un sistema de notificaciones, pero hice una pequeña adición a la conexión y me sale este error:

```
Warning: mysqli num rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli result, boolean given
```

Pero no sé que significa o que me quisiera dar a entender.

```
<?php
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "antetodopopayan");
    $count = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM informacion WHERE estado = 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if(!$conexion){
    echo "error";
}else{

}

?>
```

Comment: que intentas obtener con esa query?

Comment: si como habias dicho un contador

Comment: ¿que pena molestarle pero no me a funsionado?  T-T

Comment: prueba la respuesta que te dejé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno de acuerdo a la zona de comentarios, mencionas querer hacer un contador de esa consulta. por lo que deberías usar una función de agregación como `COUNT()` dado lo anterior te propongo que tu código luzca así:

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "antetodopopayan");
$consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as T FROM informacion WHERE estado = 0");
$fila = $consulta->fetch_assoc();
echo $fila["T"];
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. Como notas use mejor un estilo orientado a objetos con `new mysqli`
2. Como voy a hacer un conteo de las filas que entren en una condición, a ese mismo conteo le coloco un alias, en este caso `T`
3. En una variable `$fila` asigno que la consulta use el método `fetch_assoc()`
4. Como paso final como trato de imprimir la cantidad de filas que entran dada la condición en el `WHERE` hago un echo de dicha variable, pero accediendo a la clave que coloque que es `T`

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si deseas manejar el estado de la conexión entonces tu código debería quedar de este modo

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "antetodopopayan");

if($conexion->connect_errno){
    return $conexion->connect_error;
}else{
    $consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as T FROM informacion WHERE estado = 0");
    $fila = $consulta->fetch_assoc();
    echo $fila["T"];
}
```

Comment: vale, si funsiono gracias